# Add action on ObservableList item in javafx

Tags: javafx-2

I am using javafx to make a ListView in which add Observable List which contains buttons.
I want to add action on each buttons in this lists.Any help...

```
ObservableList videoLists = null;
    if (listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals("class 8")) {
        classTitleID.setText("class 8 video lists");
        File physicsFolder = new File("D:\\videos\\physics");
        File[] listOfFiles = physicsFolder.listFiles();
        videoLists = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                videoLists.add(new Button(file.getName()));
                physicsListview.setItems(videoLists);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

simply do

```
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
    Button button = new Button(file.getName());
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            //your action
        }
    });
            videoLists.add(button);
            physicsListview.setItems(videoLists);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I want to add different actions on each buttons in the ObservableList. How can I achieve this....

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to have `Node` subclasses as the data type in `ListView`s (or `TableView`s, `ComboBox`es, etc): it breaks MVC. Make your `ListView` a `ListView<File>` and use a `cellFactory` to show the button in the `ListView` cells. You can set the action handler there.

```
ListView<File> physicsListview = new ListView<>();
ObservableList<File> videoLists = FCollections.observableArrayList();
//...
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
  if (file.isFile()) {
    videoLists.add(file);
  }
}
physicsListview.setItems(videoLists);

physicsListview.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<File>, ListCell<File>>() {
  @Override
  public ListCell<File> call(ListView<File>()) {
    final Button button = new Button();
    return new ListCell<File>() {
      @Override
      public void updateItem(final File item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
          setGraphic(null);
        } else {
          button.setText(item.getName());
          button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
              // handle action. 
              // You can access the File object item here if needed
            }
          });
          setGraphic(button);
        }
      }
    };
  });
});
```